# Is there a way to know whether a post is being used as a pending audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits, timeline

Currently, on the sites with review audits enabled (SO, SU, SF, AU, SoftwareEng, Maths), you can see if a post is used for review audits by visiting its timeline:

```
https://<siteurl>/posts/<id>/timeline
```

You'll then see two times for each audit: The time the system decided to use the post as one, and the time the audit is completed. But there's always two times, meaning you only see completed audits there.

Question: Can one see if there's a **pending** audit (chosen as, but not completed) anyway?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No; pending reviews - including audits - are excluded from the timeline by design.

Comment: What's the reason for that? I would sometimes think it's useful to see pending reviews (not necessarily audits), for example if I flag an answer as NAA or VLQ, I want to see how many users have reviewed my flag and how they've reviewed it, and if I vote to close or reopen a question I would like to see how many users have voted to leave open/leave closed (it's already possible to see how many users have voted to close or reopen).

Comment: There are a few ways in which reviews can be manipulated unfairly if they're easy to find while still active, @DonaldDuck. Also, even if you *could* find them, there's no easy way to tell who or how many have reviewed until the review has completed.

Comment: @​Shog9 On posts that I flagged or voted to close myself outside of the queue (which are the posts for which I'm usually interested in seing pending reviews), it usually says "this item is not reviewable" and then a list of the users who reviewed it and how they reviewed it. It would be nice to have a link to those like for suggested edits. When I suggest an edit, it says "Thanks for your edit! Your edit will only be visible to you until it is peer reviewed" with a link to the review item. It would be nice to have something similar for flags.